# PHP array has only one entry,how to get its key?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr['thisiskey'] = 1；
```

Like above,how to get "thisiskey" programmatically?

Answer (score 8):

Use `array_keys`:

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
var_dump($keys[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution:

```
key($arr);
```

key returns current key of the array

Answer (score 1):

Iteratively:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){

    print $key . ' = ' . $value .'\n';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . PHP_EOL;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
list($key, ) = each($arr);
print $key;
```